# What is the space between these elements?

Tags: html

What is the spacing (the red section) between the `<div>` elements in [my code at JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b2xfpa6a/1/)? I have both padding and margin set to 0px. I don't know what's causing them. I have used F12 on chrome and determined that `.column` does not include it.

Comment: It's "whitespace" (due to `display: inline-block`): https://jsfiddle.net/b2xfpa6a/2/

Comment: Woah! I didn't realize whitespace could affect the display! Would you submit as an answer so I could set it as correct?

Comment: Because whitespace in the source code doesn't disappear magically. If you don't want that space, see [How to remove the space between inline-block elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5078239/1529630)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the space between `inline-blocks` elements.

There are many ways to fix this, including:

- Adding a negative margin to your elements
- Giving a `font-size` of `0` to the parents
- Removing the space between the closing and next opening tags with comments

You can see a highlight of these methods [here](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements).

Answer (score -1):

You can solve it applying these rules

```
.boardCell {float:left;}
.column {display:block;}
```